# how to know file size of all linked files like in a web page at once?

Tags: firefox, web-development

how to get file size of all linked files in a web page at once? without downloading them.

like pdf, wmv, mp3 , quicktime etc.

Comment: You sure come up with interesting questions. =)

Answer (score 1):

For both of these Methods, I am assuming you want to measure the size of a page as well as all the pages it links to, with all their resources and not a single page with its resources.

Easiest way is probably to use something like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) and point it to your site, then look at all the files it pulled and get their size - not that accurate as it adds a header and footer, but the easiest way I can think of if you do not have access to the files.

If you do have access, just select them manually and look at properties.

Comment: I want to take size only images, pdf, flv, quicktimr, mp3 etc

Comment: From reading your other comment about the PDF and FLV files - I think your best bet is to just get HTTrack and use it, set it to 0 link depth and it should be able to download everything related to the page you select. Obviously it will actually download it all... but you will know the exact size of everything.

Comment: can we just see size without downloading

Comment: Not easily or automatically (AFAIK) the site will just say "item.flv" unless you connect to or request a download (even if you don't actually download it) there is no way to know its size.

Answer (score 1):

The [Get File Size](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6656) add-on can tell you the size for each individual file, but not at the same time. How it works is that it requests the content length header of the remote file. If the server is configured properly, it will tell you the size without you having to download it:

[image]

Comment: no i need to know size for all file at once

Answer (score 0):

Get the ["View Dependencies" add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2214) for Firefox.  Load the webpage in Firefox.  Go to "View Dependencies" under the **Tools** menu.

The window that opens will list all the files that were loaded in order to show the page, along with their sizes in KB.

Comment: no it's not showing any info about linked pdf and flv

Comment: well, you can see the SWF on a YouTube page -- that's the video player, so that's the only "dependency" that Firefox knows about.  the FLV playing isn't counted because the SWF loads that through the Flash plugin.  ... i don't use a PDF plugin but i'd assume that's similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the HTTP HEAD request for each item.  That will give you the size in the returned header without getting the file itself.

Comment: please tell me how

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the files/direct links to files into a downloader and check the total size..